# i am not able to use the col-lg for columns in bootstrap 5 though it is working perfectly fine for bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

column
    
    
        column

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style=" background-color:yellow; border:1px solid">
    column

</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style=" background-color:yellow; border:1px solid">
    column
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style=" background-color:yellow; border:1px solid">
    column
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style=" background-color:yellow; border:1px solid">
    column
</div>
```

i tried this it worked perfectly fine for bootstrap 4 but not for bootstrap 5. can anyone tell how  to resolve it??

Answer (score 0):

Are you wrapping these `cols` into a `row`?

I mean something like this:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style=" background-color:yellow; border:1px solid"> column </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style=" background-color:yellow; border:1px solid"> column </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style=" background-color:yellow; border:1px solid"> column </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style=" background-color:yellow; border:1px solid"> column </div>
</div>
```

Also, make sure you're importing resources in the proper way as documented [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/).

Comment: actuallly i had left it thanks for the help now i am able to do it properly.